# Solving a differential equation involving $y$ and its exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi all I have a question Ive been asked to solve. But I have no idea where to begin.

The equation is $y'=\dfrac{y+e^x}{x+e^y}$.

I think this is homogeneous but I have no idea as to how to manipulate this to get it into the required form.

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that you have an equation where $$y' = f\left( {x,y} \right) = \frac{1}{{f\left( {y,x} \right)}}$$

Comment: I do not think it it homogeneous.

Comment: A solution is given by $y(x)=x$ .

Comment: In general, if you have a solution $y=f(x)$ the inverse function $y=f^{-1}(x)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Even if the diff-equation cannot be solved, you can get a pretty good understanding of the solution by noting that the function is monotonously increasing and approaches $y=x$ for large $x$.

Comment: Given that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208254/first-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential-equation/208465#208465 can be transformed into Abel equation of the second kind, I am thinking that whether this question can be transformed into Abel equation of the second kind or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maple 16 does not find a closed-form solution, or any symmetries.  This strongly suggests that there is no closed-form solution.  Almost certainly there are no closed-form solutions that can be found by elementary techniques.

Comment: How about $y(x)=x$ suggested by @Fabian ?

Comment: Neither does Mathematica 8.

Comment: Maybe the OP made a typo and forgot a minus sign?

Comment: @Fabian Maybe. If so, it'd be exact and everthing would be OK.

Comment: @Sasha: ok, that's one closed-form solution, but not a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can write the ode in the form $\omega=Mdx+Ndy=0,$ where $M=-(y+e^x)$ and $N=x+e^y.$
This means that we replace the search for solutions of the ode with the search for curves $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ such that $\gamma^\ast\omega=0.$

As showed in Peter Tamaroff's answer $\omega$ is not closed $d\omega\neq 0.$
However it can be showed (invoking Frobenius'theorem) that there exists a function $\mu$ not vanishing s.t. $\mu\omega$ is exact, i.e. $d(\mu\omega)=0.$

To find $\mu$ we need a solution for the $1^{\textrm{st}}$-order linear pde $$0=\frac{\partial \mu N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial\mu M}{\partial y}\equiv(x+e^y)\partial_x\mu+(y+e^x)\partial_y\mu+2\mu.$$

Comment: ... which is as hard to solve as the original ode.

Comment: I posted it just to make explicit my difficulty.